# Gerund after "ways to"

Tags: grammar, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

I'm writing a paper with a colleague and we are unsure if the grammar in our title is correct. I'd like to go with this variant.

> Multiple Ways to Measuring Alertness

My colleague asks if we should change the title to

> Multiple Ways to Measure Alertness

As far as I understand the Gerund, only the first variant is correct. Is that true? ;)

**Edit**: Based on the comments, would the word "approach" change the grammar in this case?

> Multiple Approaches to Measuring Alertness
>
> Multiple Approaches to Measure Alertness

Comment: It's either "ways to measure" or "ways of measuring."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

"Multiple **Ways of Measuring** Alertness"

OR

"Multiple **Ways to Measure** Alertness"

Comment: Your answer is just a repeat of deadrat's comment.

Comment: It's fine to use a comment as the **basis** of an answer, but please explain **why** those are the forms to use.

Comment: If I had a good explanation, I would have given my own answer.  Notice we can say "Multiple Approaches to Measuring Alertness."

Comment: Is there a difference between "ways" and "approaches" regarding the grammar? "Approaches" also sounds nice. I'll update the question

Comment: @InterestedUser The crucial point is that "measure" is an infinitival and thus follows the infinitival marker "to". By contrast, "measuring" is a gerund-participle which follows a prep, and since "ways" typically selects the prep "of", not "to", it follows that _multiple ways of measuring alertness is correct_. Things are different with "approaches", which selects the prep "to", so _multiple approaches to measuring alertness_ is fine. (note that infinitival "to measure" would not be correct with "approaches".)

Comment: @BillJ  I can't find the term infinitival. Where is that term used, in what school of linguistics?

Comment: Oh, it's just a term for any construction that contains (or is comprised of) the traditional 'infinitive' form of a verb.